# How can I use multiple filters at a time in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the code below, when I'm using `filter:filterText` all the 3 parameters are getting filtered. If I want any of the two parameters to be filtered what expression can I use there?

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText"></input>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="friend in friends|filter:filterText">
            ({{friend.name}},{{friend.phone}},{{friend.mail}})
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myapp1=angular.module("myApp",[]);
    myapp1.controller("someController",function($scope,$filter){
        $scope.friends=[
            {
                name:"asdf",
                phone:"123456",
                mail:"asd@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                name:"qwe",
                phone:"456887",
                mail:"qwer@yahoo.com"
            },
            {
                name:"cvb",
                phone:"7786887",
                mail:"some@gmail.com"
            }
        ];
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By defining an object for the filter, you can define which fields you want to filter. The following example only searches in the fields `name` and `mail`:

```js
var myapp1=angular.module("myApp",[]);

myapp1.controller("someController",function($scope,$filter){
  $scope.friends=[{
    name:"asdf",
    phone:"123456",
    mail:"asd@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    name:"qwe",
    phone:"456887",
    mail:"qwer@yahoo.com"
  },
  {
    name:"cvb",
    phone:"7786887",
    mail:"some@gmail.com"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="someController">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="filterName" />
    Email: <input type="text" ng-model="filterEmail" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="friend in friends|filter:{ name: filterName, mail: filterEmail}">
        ({{friend.name}},{{friend.phone}},{{friend.mail}})
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that version returns element with the same name and mail address

Comment: thats true, the old version checked if the defined strings is contained in the `name` and `email`. I have updated my snipped, so now a string for name and a string for email can be provided

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this : 

<input type="text" ng-model="filterName" placeholder="by name"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="filterMail" placeholder="by mail"/>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends|filter:filterName|| filterMail">
        ({{friend.name}},{{friend.phone}},{{friend.mail}})
    </li>
</ul>
```